# Find the closest value by property with Stream API

Tags: java, list, java-stream, reduce, minimum

I am currently working on some Java code that has a goal:

- Receive list of `Collection<ForecastPerDate>` (see below);
- Find items that have `date >= today`;
- Get the `value` of the item with date closest to *today* (minimum `diff`);
- Floor it and round it;
- If no data has been found, it should fallback to `0` with a log message.

```java
public record ForecastPerDate(String date, Double value) {}
```

My implementation so far seems pretty efficient and sane to me, but I don't like mutating variables or state (I am becoming more of a Haskell dev lately haha) and always quite liked using the Streams API of Java.

Just FYI the project uses Java 17 so that helps. I assume this probably can be solved with a `reduce()` function and some accumulator but I am unclear on how to, at least without causing more than one iteration.

Here is the code:

```java
 @Override
    public Long getAvailabilityFromForecastData(final String fuCode,
                                                final String articleCode,
                                                final Collection<ForecastPerDate> forecasts) {
        if (forecasts == null || forecasts.isEmpty()) {
            log.info(
                    "No forecasts received for FU {} articleCode {}, assuming 0!",
                    fuCode,
                    articleCode
            );
            return 0L;
        }

        final long todayEpochDay = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay();
        final Map<String, Double> forecastMap = new HashMap<>();
        long smallestDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String smallestDiffDate = null;

        for (final ForecastPerDate forecast : forecasts) {
            final long forecastEpochDay = LocalDate.parse(forecast.date()).toEpochDay();
            final long diff = forecastEpochDay - todayEpochDay;

            if (diff >= 0 && diff < smallestDiff) {
                // we look for values in present or future (>=0)
                smallestDiff = diff;
                smallestDiffDate = forecast.date();
                forecastMap.put(forecast.date(), forecast.value());
            }
        }

        if (smallestDiffDate != null) {
            final Double wantedForecastValue = forecastMap.get(smallestDiffDate);
            if (wantedForecastValue != null) {
                return availabilityAmountFormatter(wantedForecastValue);
            }
        }

        log.info(
                "Resorting to fallback for FU {} articleCode {}, 0 availability for article!  Forecasts: {}",
                fuCode,
                articleCode,
                forecasts
        );
        return 0L;
    }

    private Long availabilityAmountFormatter(final Double raw) {
        return Math.round(Math.floor(raw));
    }
```

EDIT: In the end after all suggestions here, a nice little algorithm came out:

```java
    private static Long toEpochDay(final String date) {
        return LocalDate.parse(date).toEpochDay();
    }

    @Override
    public Long getAvailabilityFromForecastData(final String fuCode,
                                                final String articleCode,
                                                final Collection<ForecastPerDate> forecasts) {
        final long today = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay();
        final String fallbackMessage = "Resorting to fallback for FU {} articleCode {},"
                + " 0 availability for article! Forecasts: {}";

        if (forecasts == null) {
            log.info(fallbackMessage, fuCode, articleCode, null);
            return 0L;
        }

        final Optional<ForecastPerDate> result = forecasts.stream()
                .filter(fpd -> toEpochDay(fpd.date()) > today)
                .min(Comparator.comparing(fpd -> toEpochDay(fpd.date()) - today));

        if (result.isPresent()) {
            return availabilityAmountFormatter(result.get().value());
        } else {
            log.info(fallbackMessage, fuCode, articleCode, forecasts);
            return 0L;
        }
    }

    private Long availabilityAmountFormatter(final Double raw) {
        return Math.round(Math.floor(raw));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach.

- stream the collection of objects
- filter out any dates older than and including today.
- then collect using `Collectors.minBy` and a special comparator.
- then use the result with the rest of your code to either return the value or log the result.

```
public Long getAvailabilityFromForecastData(final String fuCode,
        final String articleCode,
        final Collection<ForecastPerDate> forecasts) {
    
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
    
    Comparator<ForecastPerDate> comp =
            Comparator.comparing(f -> LocalDate.parse(f.date(), dtf),
                    (date1, date2) -> date1.compareTo(date2));
    
    Optional<ForecastPerDate> result = forecasts.stream()
            .filter(fpd -> LocalDate.parse(fpd.date(),dtf)
                    .isAfter(LocalDate.now()))
            .collect(Collectors.minBy(comp));
    
    if (result.isPresent()) {
        return availabilityAmountFormatter(result.get().value());
    }
    log.info(
            "Resorting to fallback for FU {} articleCode {}, 0 availability for article!  Forecasts: {}",
            fuCode, articleCode, forecasts);
    return 0L;
}
```

**Demo**

Note: for this answer and demo I included in the above method a `DateTimeFormatter` since I don't know the format of your dates. You will probably need to alter it for your application.

```
        List<ForecastPerDate> list = List.of(
                new ForecastPerDate("6/14/2022", 112.33),
                new ForecastPerDate("6/19/2022", 122.33),
                new ForecastPerDate("6/16/2022", 132.33),
                new ForecastPerDate("6/20/2022", 142.33));
        long v = getAvailabilityFromForecastData("Foo","Bar", list);
        System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
132 (based on current day of 6/15/2022)
```

If no dates are present after the current day, `0` will be returned and the issue logged.

**Updated**

I believe this will be somewhat more efficient since the dates only need to be parsed a single time.

You can put date and the actual `ForecastPerDate` object in an `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` and at the same time parse the `LocalDate`.

- Stream as before.
- create the entry (i.e. `map(fpd -> new SimpleEntry<>( LocalDate.parse(fpd.date(), dtf), fpd))`

  - this parses the date and stores as the key, the record is the value.
- Now that the date is parsed you can filter as before by getting the key from the entry.
- The `minBy` Comparator is also simpler since there are pre-existing Entry comparators for key and value. So use
  `.collect(Collectors.minBy(Entry.comparingByKey()));`

Putting it all together.

```
Optional<Entry<LocalDate, ForecastPerDate>> result = forecasts
        .stream()
        .map(fpd -> new SimpleEntry<>(
                LocalDate.parse(fpd.date(), dtf), fpd))
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().isAfter(LocalDate.now()))
        .collect(Collectors.minBy(Entry.comparingByKey()));
```

To get the result there is one extra level of indirection. Get the Optional contents followed by the `Entry.value()` and then the `value` from `ForecastPerDate` object.

```
if (result.isPresent()) {
    return availabilityAmountFormatter(result.get().getValue().value());
}
```

Comment: BTW, the above could be simplified if the `ForecastPerDate` record already contained a `LocalDateTime` instead of a String.  That would eliminate all the extra parsing.  But that may be beyond your control.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume this probably can be solved with a `reduce()`

It's a perfectly valid use case for `reduce()`.

I have one proposal regarding the structure of `ForecastPerDate`. It would be far more convenient to store the date as `LocalDate` and not as `String`. That is the correct way of dealing with dates, because there's a little you can do with a string representing the date without parsing.

And even if you don't consider the idea of changing the `ForecastPerDate` as a possible option, it would not be difficult to adopt the following approach.

I'll proceed with `ForecastPerDate` record defined as follows:

```
public record ForecastPerDate(LocalDate date, Double value) {}
```

> Find items that have `date >= today`

When we need to compare the two `LocalDate` objects there's no need to extract day from epoch and manipulate with them manually, basically it's a violation of the *Information expert principle* because `LocalDate` instances are capable to compare their data. Just let them do that by using `ifAfter()` and `equals()`.

And there's no need for the intermediate `Map`. We can perform the reduction on the `ForecastPerDate` objects by always picking the one with the closest upcoming date.

In the code below, [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) produces the result as an `Optional<ForecastPerDate>` (because *identity* is not provided) which gets transformed into `Optional<Long>`. If optional is empty, then a default value of `0L` will be provided.

That's how it might look like:

```
public static Long getAvailabilityFromForecastData(final String fuCode,
                                                   final String articleCode,
                                                   final Collection<ForecastPerDate> forecasts) {
    // writing a log message
    
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    
    Long mostClosestForecastValue = forecasts.stream()
        .filter(forecast -> forecast.date().isAfter(now) || forecast.date.equals(now)) // today in the future
        .filter(forecast -> forecast.value() != null)
        .reduce((result, next) -> result.date().isBefore(next.date()) ? result : next) // Optional<ForecastPerDate>
        .map(forecast -> availabilityAmountFormatter(forecast.value())) // Optional<Long>
        .orElse(0L); // extracting Long value from the optional
    
    // writing a log message
    
    return mostClosestForecastValue;
}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sfe)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the operations you mention are available method-calls on streams.

- Receive list of Collection -> `forecasts.stream()`
- Find items that have date >= today -> `.filter()`
- Get the "value" of the item with date closest to today (minimum diff) -> `.min()`, giving an `Optional<ForecastPerDate>`
- Floor it and round it -> `optional.map()`
- If no data has been found it should fallback to 0 with a log message -> `optional.orElseGet()`

Put together, it would be something like this (I haven't compiled it, so it probably won't work on the first try):

```
@Override
public Long getAvailabilityFromForecastData(final String fuCode,
                                            final String articleCode,
                                            final Collection<ForecastPerDate> forecasts) {

    var today = LocalDate.now();

    return forecasts.stream()
        .filter(forecast -> !today.isBefore(LocalDate.parse(forecast.date())))
        .min(Comparator.comparing(forecast -> 
             Duration.between(today, LocalDate.parse(forecast.date()))
        .map(forecast -> availabilityAmountFormatter(forecast.value()))
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            log.info("No forecasts found");
            return 0L;
        });
}
```

I would move some of the logic into `ForecastPerDate` to avoid having to parse `forecast.date()` multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep a similar flow to what you have, try something like this:

```
final LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
return forecasts.stream()
        .map(ForecastPerDate::date)
        .map(LocalDate::parse)
        .filter(fd -> fd.isEqual(now) || fd.isAfter(now))
        .min()
        .map(LocalDate::toString)
        .map(forecastMap::get)
        .map(this::availabilityAmountFormatter)
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            log.info("Resorting to fallback...");
            return 0L;
        });
```